# finding the number of results with index match in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table that looks like this:

`Cx` denotes columns

```
C1 C2 C3    
A  B  C    
A  E  F    
A  B  E    
A  B  C
A  B  D
```

I know I can use index match to match against two criteria (for example, if I search for `C1=A` and `C2=B`) to get the result in another column (to get `C` in `C3`).

1. How would I go about finding the number of matches based on the criteria (the number of times where `C1=A` and `C2=B` which is three times based on the table above)?
2. How would I go about finding the number of results with Cs based on 1. queries?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your second question? An example will be very welcomed.

Comment: @Vylix for example, I want to find use index match with criteria C1= A, C2=B, which will give me the result C if I specify it to return C3 as a result. I want to know if theres any way for me to count the number of C based on the criteria C1=A and C2=B? Thanks!

Comment: C1=A, C2=B is 4 times, in your example and return C 2 times is it the result you want to return?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use INDEX-MATCH? This sounds like a straightforward COUNTIFS application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sumproduct to count C1="A" and C2="B" use the following:
`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="A")*(B2:B6="B"))`
and to count how many times it will return C use the following:
`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="A")*(B2:B6="B")*(C2:C6="C"))`

A2:A6="A" if True will return 1
B2:B6="B" if True will return 1
The product 1*1 will return 1
Sumproduct will return the sum of 1
The same for the second formula when the three conditions are True 1*1*1=1 it will return 1

Comment: You don't need the `--`s in your formulas because you're using `*`. Any math operator applied to those will convert them from Boolean to numerical values.

Comment: Thanks this works! If I want to find out if A2:A6="A" and B2:B6="B", then what are the total number of Cs and Fs (which is 3), how can I do it?

Comment: If you need the numbers of C and F together you have to add =SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="A")*(B2:B6="B")*(C2:C6="C"))+SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="A")*(B2:B6="B")*(C2:C6="F")) but in your data you have A  E  F  not A  B  F